# Scrollback on Putty

Tags: windows-7, putty

I'm using Putty with Windows 7, and scrollback doesn't work at all - cannot scroll back even 1 line. Number of scrollback lines in the settings is set to 2000.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the option "Display scrollbar" enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is enabled

Comment: Here's a related SF question: http://serverfault.com/questions/32313/putty-and-screen-and-scroll-back-buffer